# Match the same strings with different preceding zero width pattern

Tags: vim

I want to find the following matches of **foo** and **bar**, which the receiver of the email is the `username`. That is :

```
username:"foo",web:"foo.com",email:"foo@foo.com"
```

--> match both of **foo** in username and email, not in web

```
username:"bar",web:"bar.com",email:"bar@bar.com"
```

--> match both of **bar** in username and email, not in web

```
username:"vi",web:"vi.com",email:"vim@vi.com"
```

--> no match

Here are the failed expression I tried:

```
\(username:"\)\@<=[^"]\+\(".*email:"\)\@<=\1@
```

results in no match.
Is it possible to find these matches ?

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it. You needed to put brackets around the username part and use `\2` rather than `\1`:

```
\(username:"\)\@<=\([^"]\+\)\(.*email:"\2@\)\@=
```

If you just want to match lines rather than pull out the username, you can simplify to

```
username:"\([^"]*\).*email:"\1@
```

Answer (score 0):

With your example, this line should help:

```
\v(web:"[^"]{-})@<!(foo|bar)
```

[image]